# Gradient calculated with Directional Derivative not similar to Gradient calculated with Product Rule for $X^{T}X$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Calculate the gradient of $f(X) = X^{T}X$

Using Directional Derivative 
$ Df(X) \cdot H = \lim_{t\to0}  \frac{(X+tH)^{T}(X+tH) - X^TX}{t} = X^{T}H + H^{T}X$

Using Product Rule 
$Df(X) = X^{T} \cdot D(X) + D(X^{T}) \cdot X = X^{T} + X $ 
$Df(X)\cdot H = (X^{T} + X) \cdot H = X^{T} \cdot H + X \cdot H$

What am i getting wrong ? They should be the same. $X^{T}H + H^{T}X$ is symmetric but not equal to  $X^{T}H + XH$.

Comment: The second equality on the fifth line is totally wrong. How is $D(X)$ just multiplication by the identity matrix? However, $$Df(X)H = X^\top\cdot\big(D(X)H \big)+ \big(D(X^\top)H\big)\cdot X = X^\top H + H^\top X.$$

Comment: Your use of the product rule is incorrect.

Comment: @TedShifrin i see how you can apply Product Rule with the Directional Derivative. But isn't it possible to use the product rule to calculate the gradient directly (without the direction) ? And $f(X) = X$ then $Df(X) = I$ and $D(f \cdot g) = f \cdot Dg + g \cdot Df $?

Comment: Think it through carefully. This is the identity map on the space of $n\times n$ matrices, not itself an $n\times n$ matrix at all!

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't get it. Is $Df(X)=I$ with $f(X)=X$ not true? And what is $Df(X)$ then ? And how does the Product Rule Apply in this case. Product Rule without the directional derivative.

Comment: You refuse to think about domains and ranges of functions here. And you have a product rule in mind that doesn’t make sense. Find a concrete statement in a textbook and edit your post to include it.

Comment: Further comment for you to understand: If $L\colon M_{n\times n}\to M_{n\times n}$ is linear, very, very rarely is $L(H) =AH$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

Answer (score 2):

$
\require{enclose}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\l{\ell}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\F{F_{ij}}
\def\d{\delta}
\def\Ek{E_{k\l}}
\def\El{E_{\l k}}
\def\X{X_{k\l}}
$There is a very general product rule for the ***differential*** of two arbitrary tensors {$A,B$} and any product {$\star$} with which they are dimensionally compatible.
$$\eqalign{
d(A\star B) &= (A+dA)\star(B+dB) \;-\; A\star B \\
 &= \big(A\star B +A\star dB +dA\star B +dA\star dB\big) \;-\; A\star B \\
 &= A\star dB + dA\star B + (\enclose{horizontalstrike}{dA\star dB}) \\
 &= A\star dB + dA\star B \\
}$$
This rule is only valid for differentials. It cannot be applied to gradients or directional derivatives or other types of derivatives.

In the current problem {$\star$} is the ordinary matrix product and
$\,\{A,B\}=\{X^T,X\}$

Therefore, for the matrix-valued function $F=f(X)\;$ we have
$$\eqalign{
F &= X^TX \qiq
dF &= X^TdX + dX^TX \\
}$$
The ***directional derivative*** can be recovered by setting $\:dX=H.$

Unfortunately, the ***gradient*** is a fourth-order tensor which is impossible to render using standard matrix notation. However, the component-wise gradient is merely matrix-valued and is obtained by setting $\,dX=\Ek\;$ (which is a matrix whose elements are all zero except for the $(k,\l)$ element which is equal to one)
$$\eqalign{
\grad X\X &= \Ek \qiq
\grad F\X
 &= X^T\Ek + \Ek^TX
\;=\; X^T\Ek+ \El X \\
}$$
Taking the $(i,j)$ component of each term in this expression (and introducing [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) symbols) yields the fully indexed form of the tensor gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad \F\X
 &= X_{ik}^T\d_{\l j} + \d_{i\l}X_{kj}
\;=\; \d_{j\l}X_{ki} + \d_{i\l}X_{kj} \\
}$$
With this tensor expression (and some familiarity with index notation) you can calculate anything you need regarding the behavior of the $F$ matrix.